# How do I disable the "Add to My Links" option on a list Actions Menu?

Tags: 2007, my-site, shared-service-provider

I have a SharePoint 2007 farm where MySites and MyLinks are disabled and there is only one SSP.  The 'My Links' menu option that is normally next to the Welcome Control is properly trimmed away.  Unfortunately, for every list in the site collection, it still shows the "Add to My Links" menu option in the Actions menu for the list.

Some sites I've looked at have recommended updating the core.js to remove this, which I did as a test but to no avail (I know, I know, core MS file, do not touch).  Upon deeper investigation, I discovered that this troublesome link is part of the initial page rendering, not added dynamically via Javascript.  This means that the default SharePoint controls are where this is being adding to the page.

How do I disable just this menu option?

Comment: i have got exactly the same requirement, iam trying to get the solution for this..., did you ever fixed this problem, if yes please share the steps, it will be very very helpful to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps:

Open your Site collection with a Web browser and go to:

Site Settings => Site Collection Administration => Portal Site Connection

Then choose "Do not connect to portal site"

Worked for me.

Comment: That would probably work but we need the other features that the portal link provides, most notably the breadcrumbs across the top.  Without that, users do not have a way to get back to the root that is above the site collection.

Comment: Well in this case, and ruling out JavaScript/jQuery, you are stuck with either messing with internal files (which I never do) or develop a custom feature with a .NET control and deploy it to your farm.

Comment: That's pretty much what I was afraid of.  I was hoping for a big shiny red button that said "Turn off this link across the farm"  ... I can dream

Comment: @Dave, you indicated that adding JavaScript/jQuery is not possible/allowed (maybe by company policy?). Does the same apply to a custom feature with a .NET control deployed as SharePoint solution package (aka WSP)? If not, I could lend you a hand to create such a feature. In fact I was able to prototype such a feature already in about an hour and it would just need some polishing.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer as it lists the most likely solutions.  I was hoping for a setting that could be checked/unchecked but that does not appear to be an option

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using jQuery if you are comfortable with that. Basically you have to remove the option from the menu. I have done this and will add the code as soon as I can find it!

Comment: Unfortunately, this site does not and cannot have jQuery, nor can I include an additional JS file in order to do it the "old" way via standard JavaScript.